# Paragraph Control?

Tags: html, css

i'm dealing with a weird problem i'm working in my site to try to make a table for movies, the problem comes on the paragraph location, it's position must be in the right part in full screen browser and in left in non full screen browser, how every is not behaving how is should, it das what is has to do only in 90 % zoom of any browser, i try all 4 major browsers , in all it was the same weird stuff.

So the paragraf added after a table only shows in the right side where it has to be in full screen only in the browser is at 90% zoom.

I'm going to add 3 images so i make it more clear :

This is how it looks in non full screen this ok :

[image]

This is how it looks in full screen and is not ok since it has to be in the right side :

[image]

This is the way it supposed to look like only it shows up like this what if the user has the browser at 90 % zoom !!

[image]

How to make it show up in the right side of the user does not have the browser at 90% ?

I try : float:right;
I try : white-space: pre-wrap; using 
 before the paragraph...

i also try top: -400px; it shows up ok in full screen but it overlaps the table in non full screen..

Some please help with this i have never seen something like this..

Comment: So, where's the code? [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to see some code but I suspect your issue is your total width of the two columns is wider than 100%.  You might have the widths explicitly set to total 100%, but maybe you haven't factored in margin, borders, etc, that may make the width wider than the available space, causing the second paragraph to wrap.  When you zoom out, you now have "more" than 100% width, which is why it looks right.

Try setting your column widths such that they total 90%... if that works then you need to figure out what's making your columns wider than you expect.

Comment: Any chance you can link to a page that actually renders the finished screen?  Hard to debug this as-is.

Comment: The problem was right before my eyes, it was stupid of me not to see, it was in the width of the div class... thx Jeff for makeing my eyes look there..